# angular webpack works with real backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I am using webpack + angular to develop the project. one problem is that when I start my localhost, angular cannot get data from real backend.
angular is running at localhost:8080, and the real API is at http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8080/getTable.html

if I write the url directly in angular, I would have below error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8080/getTable.html. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

anybody has solution to this? thanks

Comment: You need to enable CORS - Cross Origin Resource Sharing. It happens when your front end and backend are on different urls. What kind of server do you use for serving the backend?

Comment: More information related to the topic here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: @NevyanovL   , for backend side, does it need to do any change? thanks

Comment: What kind of server do you use for your backend? You need to focus on enabling CORS on this server. I did it on tomcat 8 and it was in the configuration file of tomcat. Additional filter was the solution. It is worth at least trying it.